# Django Admin With Docker Error Incorrect padding

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

When I try to access to my Django admin site With Docker I got the following error:

[image]

but With out Docker , it can work

[image]

How to fix this?
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED l
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==2.2
```

Does anyone have some ideas or same issue? Thanks!

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answer if your question was successfully answered.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You seem to have bad sessions in your session cache for some reason, possibly due to Django session backend or hashing algorithm differences. Consider removing them and try again.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session.objects.all().delete()
```

Also, ensure you’ve added `*.pyc` And `**/__pycache__` files to `.dockerignore`. If you don’t do this your docker code will run code compiled by the machine outside of the container—this can cause strange and/or dangerous bugs.

## References

Rationale for adding .pyc files to docker ignore: [Should I add Python's pyc files to .dockerignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684674/should-i-add-pythons-pyc-files-to-dockerignore)

Comment: I was deleted seesions and it can work now. but How to createsuperuser with out commandLine because I need to use with docker @pygeek

Comment: @NokPollawat enter docker interactive shell via `docker exec run -it containername bash`. Further documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/